# Haskell random number generation

Tags: haskell, random, monads

What's the best way to handle random number generation in Haskell (or what are the tradeoffs)?

I haven't really seen an authoritative answer.

Consider: minimizing the impact on otherwise pure functions, how / when to seed, performance, thread safety

Comment: The top-rated answer on this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110535/sampling-sequences-of-random-numbers-in-haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110535/sampling-sequences-of-random-numbers-in-haskell) gives an excellent write-up of how to thread a stateful random number generator through code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, the best idea is to keep the generator in a [strict state](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Strict.html) record. Then you can use the ordinary `do`-Syntax to work with the generator. Seeding is done only once - at the beginning of the main program (or at the beginning of each thread). You can avoid IO by using the `split` operation, which yields two random generators from one. (Different, of course).

As state is still pure, threadsafety can be guaranteed. Additionally, you can always escape state by giving a random generator to the function. This is useful for instance in case of automatic unit tests.

Comment: @zoo FYI there is a decent packaging of an RNG in the state monad already on hackage (in the MonadRandom and also CryptoMonadRandom packages).  These just provide the generating in a state plus useful accessor functions to generate common types.