# Average of large number of Dice Rolls in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming

In an attempt to learn Haskell better, I'm trying to write a program that displays the average value of the sum of 2 die, rolled X number of times.  This is fairly simple in C, Java, Python... but I'm stuck in Haskell.  Here's a naive attempt:

```
import System.Random

main = do
    g <- getStdGen
    let trials = 10000000
    let rolls = take trials (randomRs (2, 12) g :: [Int])
    let average = div (sum rolls) trials
    print average
```

For low number of trials, the program works.  But when I run this code with ten million trials, I get an error:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

There's got to be a better way to write this program.  In the C, Java, and Python versions, this is a simple task.  I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110535/sampling-sequences-of-random-numbers-in-haskell) post (and understand about 75% of the material), but when I adapt that code to this situation, summing a sequence of `R [Int]` doesn't work (and I'm not sure how to 'unwrap' the [Int]).  What am I doing wrong?  What's the right way?  How do I reach random number enlightenment in Haskell?

**Edit:** in addition to the answer selected, as rtperson points out below, the modeling of 2 dice is incorrect; it should really be the sum of two independent rolls from 1 to 6.

Comment: the result is 6, SCNR :)

Comment: actually, the expected value of the sum of two dice is (1+2+3+4+5+6)/6 * 2 = 7.  The point of this exercise is to learn how to program in the language, and not so much the statistics aspect.

Comment: hehe :) there was a rounding error after calculating the expected value of one dice :)

Comment: In the linked post, the way to unwrap `R [Int]` is by using the `runRandom` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sum` is no good to sum a long list, it runs in linear space. Try this strict version of `sum`:

```
sum' = foldl' (+) 0
```

`foldl'` is defined in `Data.List`.

**EDIT** More information can be found in [this HaskellWiki article](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27).

Comment: thanks, it's been too long since I've done functional stuff.  On a side note, I wonder if it's possible to make `sum` switch from lazy to strict if program analysis yields that the calculations will be evaluated.

Comment: @benson: yes, there's such thing as strictness analysis, though I'm not sure why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @n.m. Strictness analysis is AFAIK only done when optimziations are enabled. Compiling with `ghc -O1` or higher works.

Comment: @n.m. The default is no optimization.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the probabilities are modeled incorrectly here. As the code is written, there's the same possibility of getting 2 through 12. But that's not how dice work. Of the 12 possible outcomes, there's only one way to get 2 (via 1 and 1) and 12 (through 6 and 6). But there are 6 ways to get 7 (1-6, 2-5, 3-4, 4-3, 5-2, 6-1). Modeling the roll of two dice, rather than a single 2 to 12 chance, would give the correct expected value of 7.

However -- and here's where your hair will really start to curl -- you can't simply do something like the following:

```
let rolls1 = take trials (randomRs (1, 6) g :: [Int])
let rolls2 = take trials (randomRs (1, 6) g :: [Int])
```

Because rolls1 and rolls2 will yield the same results.

```
*Main> let rolls = zip rolls1 rolls2
*Main> take 10 rolls
[(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(3,3),(5,5),(1,1),(3,3),(1,1),(3,3),(3,3)]
```

So your result will always be even, and hence remain the incorrect answer 6.

To get two distinctly random lists, you'll have to produce a new StdGen:

```
import System.Random
import Data.List

main = do
    g <- getStdGen
    b <- newStdGen   -- calls "split" on the global generator
    let trials = 10000000
    let rolls1 = take trials (randomRs (1, 6) g :: [Int])
    let rolls2 = take trials (randomRs (1, 6) b :: [Int])
    let rolls = zipWith (+) rolls1 rolls2
    let average = div (foldl' (+) 0 rolls) trials
    print average
```

(Note that I'm specifically avoiding using the State monad for this. You're welcome.)

This takes longer than the original version, but the laziness of `zipWith` combined with the strictness of `foldl'` ensure that you won't overflow the stack.

If you're just trying to fix the overflow, n.m.'s answer is correct. The strictness of `foldl'` will fix the performance issue. But in this case, getting the correct answer will also teach you something about random number generation in Haskell.

Comment: Of course, rather than getting two gens, you can just look at pairs from a single list, which is perhaps slightly cleaner :-)

Comment: @sclv - True. I was thinking backwards from the "clumsyRollDice" function on the State monad Wikibooks article (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State), which creates a new StdGen after each roll.