# Is there a way to generalise multiple generators and randoms in haskell

Tags: haskell, generator, generalization

I'm learning Haskell. 
[Average of large number of Dice Rolls in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144590/average-of-large-number-of-dice-rolls-in-haskell)
How shall I make the below code work with multiple dices say 8 dices) instead of repeatedly creating let rolls..3,4,5...etc...

```
module Dice where
import System.Random
import Data.List

dice = do
    g <- getStdGen
    b <- newStdGen
    let trials = 1000
    let rolls1 = take trials (randomRs (1,6) g :: [Int])
    let rolls2 = take trials (randomRs (1,6) b::[Int])
    let rolls = zipWith (+) rolls1 rolls2
    let average = div (foldl' (+) 0 rolls) trials
    print average
```

Comment: [hint](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+m+%5Ba%5D).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `System.Random` module offers some basic primitive, but (in my opinion) it lacks a proper monadic interface. More precisely, it offers an IO-based monadic interface, but lacks a State-based monadic interface. The latter is however [easy to define](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State) , though.

Anyway, if one wants to stick with IO and the standard generator, one could write:

```
-- (untested code)

rollDie :: Int -> IO Int
rollDie n = randomIO (1,n) -- implicitly uses the global generator

rollManyDice :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
rollManyDice howMany n = replicateM howMany (rollDie n)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   dice <- rollManyDice 20 6
   putStrLn $ "Here's 20 6-sides dice : " ++ show dice
```

where `replicateM` executes `howMany` times a monadic action, collecting all the results in a list. Here the monad is `IO`, but it could be anything.

This is a fine and simple approach, but the `IO` type above is a bit too much, preventing us to call `rollDie` from non-IO code. A `State`-based solution would not have this limination

```
type R a = State StdGen a

rollDie :: Int -> R Int
rollDie n = state $ randomR (1,n) -- uses the generator inside the State monad

rollManyDice :: Int -> Int -> R [Int]
rollManyDice howMany n = replicateM howMany (rollDie n)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   g <- getStdGen
   let dice = evalState (rollManyDice 20 6) g
   putStrLn $ "Here's 20 6-sides dice : " ++ show dice
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently as it is formulated, you only need to sum up k*N *individual* die rolls and divide them by N, where k is amount of dice you want to roll "simultaneously", N amount of trials. Summing all dice in a single roll then summing all rolls is the same as summing all dice overall.

If you want it complicated, well, make single multiroll a list of random values of specified length, sum it (you can use plain `sum` even with no optimization when k is not too large), compute the average of results.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Dice where
import System.Random
import Data.List
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

rollDie :: Int -> IO Int
rollDie n = randomRIO (1,n)

rollManyDice :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
rollManyDice howMany n = replicateM howMany (rollDie n)

dice2 = do
    dice <- rollManyDice 8 6
    putStrLn $ "Here's 20 -6 sided dice: " ++show dice
```