# Haskell - How do I get Random Points (Int,Int)

Tags: haskell, random

I'm trying to get a set of random points (x,y) for drawing graph nodes to a screen.  I need one randomly generated point for each node name passed in.

I found this code on a SO page, and modified it slightly to work for me, but it doesn't really do what I need.

I need a list of random (as random as possible) (Int,Int).

Anyway, here is what I have so far, and of course, it gives the same values every time, so it isn't particularly random :)

```
rndPoints :: [String] -> [Point]
rndPoints [] = []
rndPoints xs = zip x y where
          size = length xs
          x = take size (tail (map fst $ scanl (\(r, gen) _ -> randomR (25::Int,1000::Int) gen) (random (mkStdGen 1)) $ repeat ()))
          y = take size (tail (map fst $ scanl (\(r, gen) _ -> randomR (25::Int,775::Int) gen) (random (mkStdGen 1)) $ repeat ()))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110535/sampling-sequences-of-random-numbers-in-haskell?rq=1)

Comment: You could use Arbitrary from the QuickCheck package?

Comment: Apart from the problem of getting the same point distribution for each time the function is called, it would still be a bad idea to use twice `mkStdGen 1`. This would lead to awkward correlation between x- and y-coordinate, in the worst case resulting in only points along a line. — Anyway, having two lines that include large amounts of duplicate code is pretty much _always_ bad, there's something called [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY_principle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's clean up your code a bit. There is a plural version of `randomR` that delivers an infinite list of random values: `randomRs`. This simplifies things a bit:

```
rndPoints1 :: [String] -> [Point]
rndPoints1 [] = []
rndPoints1 xs = zip x y
  where
    size = length xs
    x = take size $ randomRs (25, 1000) (mkStdGen 1)
    y = take size $ randomRs (25,  775) (mkStdGen 1)
```

We can simplify that further, by using `zip`'s property that it stops after the shorter list is exhausted:

```
rndPoints2 :: [a] -> [Point]
rndPoints2 xs = map snd $ zip xs $ zip x y
  where
    x = randomRs (25, 1000) (mkStdGen 1)
    y = randomRs (25,  775) (mkStdGen 1)
```

Notice I've also generalized the type of incoming list to just `[a]`. Since the values are never used, they needn't be `String`s!

Now, it gives the same value every time because it uses `mkStdGen` to create a pseudo-random generator from the same seed (`1`) each time. If you want it to be different each time, then you need to create a generator in `IO` which can be based on the radom state of the computer. Rather than put the whole computation in `IO`, it is cleaner to pass in a `StdGen`:

```
rndPoints3 :: StdGen -> [Point]
rndPoints3 sg = zip x y
  where
    (sg1, sg2) = split sg
    x = randomRs (25, 1000) sg1
    y = randomRs (25,  775) sg2

pointsForLabels :: [a] -> StdGen -> [(a, Point)]
pointsForLabels xs sg = zip xs $ rndPoints3 sg

example3 :: [a] -> IO [(a, Point)]
example3 xs = newStdGen >>= return . pointsForLabels xs
```

Here, `newStdGen` creates a new pseudo-random generator each time, but it is in `IO`. That is passed eventually to a pure (non-`IO`) function `rndPoints3` that takes the generator, and returns an *infinite* list of random `Point`s. Within that function, `split` is used to create two generators from it, and each is used to derive the random list of coordinates.

`pointsForLables` now separates out the logic of matching up a new random point for each label. I also changed it to return the more likely useful pairs of labels and `Point`s.

Finally, `example3` lives in `IO`, and creates the generator and passes it all into the otherwise pure code.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So if I want to use the list of tuples that is passed back from example3, it would need to be inside a do block in the caller so that the list could then be used as parameters to another function that takes just a list [(a,Point)]?  I apologize, I'm having the hardest time with monads in this language!

Comment: How random do you want things.  The rule in haskell is, "if it could be different each time, it lives in the IO monad." It has to, because a function always returns the same result for the same input.  Put another way, Randomness lives in the real world, and is not part of a purely mathematical function.

Comment: Don't put the bulk of your program in a `do` block. Write the next step as a pure function of type `[(a, Point)] -> Whatever` and insert that into the chain in `example3`: `>>= return . frobThePairs . pointsForLabels xs`. Of course, you can make `frobThePairs` as complex as you like and it is still pure.

Comment: This answer is delightfully simple and results in a nice concise solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using MonadRandom for this. I think the code was a little clearer and easier for me to understand. You could adapt the following code to address the original question.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Random

type Point = (Float, Float)
type Poly = [Point]

randomScalar :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Float
randomScalar = getRandomR (-500, 500)

randomPoint :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Point
randomPoint = (,) <$> randomScalar <*> randomScalar

randomPoly :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Rand g Poly
randomPoly n = sequence (replicate n randomPoint)
```