# Random number sequence un Haskell and State Monad, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: haskell, random, state-monad

As part of my Haskell journey, I am implementing a raytracer and I need to be able to draw sequences of random numbers at several places in the code. Typically I would like to be able to get say 64 samples for each pixels and pixels are computed in parallel.

I was looking at the state monad to achieve that and I was guided by this answer [Sampling sequences of random numbers in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110535/sampling-sequences-of-random-numbers-in-haskell?answertab=votes#tab-top) but the code I wrote does not terminate and it's memory consumption explodes.

Here is the abstracted part of the code:
I was hopping to be able to call `sampleUniform` several time in the code to get new lists of random numbers but if I do `runhaskell test.hs`, it outputs the first character of the lis `[` and then it is stuck in an apparently infinite loop.

```
module Main (main
            , computeArray) where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State (State, evalState, get, put)
import System.Random (StdGen, mkStdGen, random)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

type Rnd a = State StdGen a

runRandom :: Rnd a -> Int -> a
runRandom action seed = evalState action $ mkStdGen seed

rand :: Rnd Double
rand = do
  gen <- get
  let (r, gen') = random gen
  put gen'
  return r

{- Uniform distributions -}
uniform01 :: Rnd [Double]
uniform01 = mapM (\_ -> rand) $ repeat ()

{- Get n samples uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 -}
sampleUniform :: Int -> Rnd [Double]
sampleUniform n = liftM (take n) uniform01

computeArray :: Rnd [Bool]
computeArray = do
  samples1 <- sampleUniform 10
  samples2 <- sampleUniform 10
  let dat = zip samples1 samples2
  return $ uncurry (<) <$> dat

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let seed = 48
  let res = runRandom computeArray seed
  putStrLn $ show res
```

Comment: See also [Why the Haskell sequence function can't be lazy or why recursive monadic functions can't be lazy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31892418/1333025)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`uniform01` threads your state through an *infinite* number of computations, which means that although it produces its *result* lazily, there is no hope of retrieving a final *state* at the end to use for the next sampling. `liftM (take n)` only affects the final value, not the state effects used to compute it.  Therefore as written, you can only use `uniform01`/`sampleUniform` once.

Instead you can thread the state through only as many `rand` actions as you use, e.g. with

```
sampleUniform n = mapM (\_ -> rand) $ replicate n ()
```

or simpler

```
sampleUniform n = sequence $ replicate n rand
```

Comment: Or even `replicateM n rand`

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation and the correct solution!

Comment: Now I can do antialiazing :) Next question is, can I use this State Monad in parallel? Or would it be better to have on state per thread? Might be for another week end :)

Comment: @olivelarouille If you want to do random numbers in parallel, you can look at the `split` function, which lets you turn one generator into several. (Which BTW could have given an alternative solution to your original problem.)